# Find merge point of two linked list?

Tags: c++, linked-list, segmentation-fault

**Hii  I am trying to solve this hackerrank question , but I am getting runtime error "segmentation fault ".

Please help me to fix this error .

Question link** = https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/find-the-merge-point-of-two-joined-linked-lists/problem

```
int findMergeNode(SinglyLinkedListNode* head1, SinglyLinkedListNode* head2) {

int length1 = 0;
int length2 = 0;

SinglyLinkedListNode* list1 = head1;
SinglyLinkedListNode* list2 = head2;

while(list1 != nullptr)
{
    list1 = list1->next;
    length1 ++;
}
while(list2 != nullptr)
{
    list2 = list2 -> next;
    length2 ++;
}

//I want to point list2 pointer to the largest list 
if(length1 > length2)
{
    SinglyLinkedListNode* temp = list1;
    list1 = list2;
    list2 = temp;     
}

for(int i=0 ; i< abs(length1 - length2) ;i++)
{
    list2 =list2 -> next;
}

while(list2 != list1)
{
    list1 = list1->next;
    list2 = list2->next;

}

return list1->data;
```

Error = I am getting "segmentation fault" error.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Questions here are expected to be complete and contain everything required to understand it without referencing other sites.  See [ask] and [mcve].  At this point you should post the question in your question (edit it).  Then for debugging segmentation fault, read https://www.cprogramming.com/debugging/segfaults.html or other sites and tutorials that show you how to do it.  Once you have narrowed the issue to a section of code, you can edit your question to let us know what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Your method of approach is fine. but after finding length of two lists, list1 and list2 would be pointing to null. Without resetting the lists to their respective heads, you are traversing with next pointers.

> list1 = head1; list2 = head2;

Set them to heads before setting largest list to list2.